# Open partial view in a DIV and use Submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button in my view, that will load feedback form inside of `div`.

```
<script>
        // open feedback window
        function openFeedback() {         
            $('#feedback-container').show();
            $('#feedback-container').load('@Url.Content("~/Feedback/")');
        }
</script>

<div id="feedback-container"></div>
<button id="feedback-button" onclick="openFeedback()">
    Give feedback
</button>
```

This loads `Index` view from `Feedback` controller. Inside I have a form with another `Submit` button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   ... some controls ...

   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

And controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Feedback());
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Feedback feedback)
    {
        SaveFeedback(feedback);
        return PartialView("ContactConfirm");
    }
```

I want to return a view with "thank you" message inside of the `feedback-container`, when form is posted back, but instead whole page is loaded - and it is only `ContactConfirm` view.

Is it possible to return a partial view into a div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ControlerName"
    , new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "post",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "feedback-container"
        }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ... some controls ...

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

It will post the form through ajax and insert the response html into the "UpdateTargetId" pointed container.

Ajax.BeginForm need jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to work. Make sure you add the js reference to your page or your js bundle, and make sure it is under your jquery reference. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is a default js library for new MVC4 project, also you can get it through [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/).

Keep in mind that ajax post cannot switch portal, i.e. you cannot post a https ajax form from a http page. So you need to make sure the landing page is forced on https if you want to make sure the login post is through https.

Comment: This is a good answer, however you need to make sure you are referencing jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js otherwise the browser will navigate away from the current page.